# How to flex column width similar to table

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, css-grid

I have a layout similar to table that contains 3 columns.
The first column is 40px，second is auto width by it content, third is the rest available width.
The rows should be highlight when hover, and have click listener.

---

Tried to use table and grid box layout. But still have some problems.

Table:

1. table-layout: fixed, can't get the real rest width.
2. table-layout: auto, can't set max-width of table.

Grid:

1. wrap cells with row, the column can't be a same width(not align).
2. unwrap, can't set the row event and style.

So, is there any solution to reslove the problems.

codepen: https://codepen.io/Woody-lxf/pen/dyOQezE

```html
<section style="width:300px">
 <main>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col1"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
   <div class="col2">type: checkbox <br/> value:1111111</div>
   <div class="col3">The Description 11111111</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col1"><input type="radio"/></div>
   <div class="col2">type: radio <br/> value:2</div>
   <div class="col3">The Description 22222222222222222222</div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <hr/>
 <main class="table">
  <div class="tr">
   <div class="td1"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
   <div class="td2">checkbox <br/> value:1</div>
   <div class="td3">The Description 11111111</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
   <div class="td1"><input type="radio"/></div>
   <div class="td2">radio <br/> value:2</div>
   <div class="td3">The Description 22222222222222222222</div>
  </div>
 </main>
</section>
```

```css
main{
 background:#f7f7f7;
}
main *{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.row{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: 40px minmax(min-content, 40px) auto;
 width:100%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.row:hover{
 background:#e6e7e8;
}
.row>*{
 padding:4px 8px;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
.col3, .td3{
 overflow:hidden;
 text-overflow:ellipsis;
}


.table{
 width:100%;
 table-layout:fixed;
 display:table;
}
.tr{
 display:table-row;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.tr:hover{
 background:#e6e7e8;
}
.tr>*{
 display:table-cell;
 padding:4px 8px;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
.td1{
 width:40px;
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want, but if I understand correctly, it can be done with flex:

```
           <div className="container">
                <div className="column1" />
                <div className="column2" />
                <div className="column3" />
            </div>
```

And css just like this:

```
.container {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column1 {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
}

.column2 {
    background: lightcoral;
    height: 100%;

}
.column2:hover {
    background: lightgreen;
}
.column2:active {
    background: yellow;
}
.column3 {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
}
```